# Miniture bluetooth enabled accelerometer with API or SDK

Tags: components, accelerometer, component-selection, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm getting into electronics as a hobby. For my first hobby project I want to build something like a super simple fitbit. To achieve this I need a bluetooth enabled accelerometer. I've had a look at alibaba ([example](http://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/NOTICE-2016-new-Bluetooth-4-0_60321406634.html?spm=a2700.7724857.29.10.CNjQtq&s=p)) - but most products seem to not have an API. Ideally I'd like an SDK also so I could connect the device to a mobile app that I'll build (my profession). My question is, is there a component that fits these requirements:

1. Battery powered
2. Small form factor (like the size of a small coin)
3. 3 axis accelerometer
4. Bluetooth enabled
5. Open API (or even better an SDK for iOS / Android)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can get a single component that does all of that, but you can certainly get a module. This will include the Bluetooth wireless chip and an accelerometer. Google "bluetooth accelerometer" and you should find lots. You should make sure the device is Bluetooth LE or Bluetooth Smart, these are designed for battery operation.